# nodejs + npm install tailwind shows error [Unsupported engine]

Tags: node.js, npm, tailwind-css

my current nodejs version: v20.10.0
npm version: 10.2.3
my os: linux mint

why it's saying my current version is { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' } ????

error message:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tailwindcss@3.3.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'postcss-import@15.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'postcss-load-config@4.0.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lilconfig@3.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'yaml@2.3.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

added 78 packages, and audited 93 packages in 37s

20 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Well, evidently you're _not_ running with the Node version you think you are running with. I'd suspect you have multiple installed.

Comment: Probably you have multiple conflicting versions installed in different paths (outside of a version manager).